# Set a preferences from an activity

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-preferences

I want explain what i need.. I've got a preference.xml in which i have a `ListPreference`.

```
<ListPreference 
                android:key="preference_grid"
                android:title="@string/preference_grid"
                android:summary="@string/preference_grid_summary"
                android:entries="@array/preference_grid_entries"
                android:entryValues="@array/preference_grid_values"
                android:defaultValue="preference_grid_none"
                />
```

Then i've created a dialog with a list of the values:

```
public void gridOnOff(View view) {
        //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Grid On/Off", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Grid Options");
        builder.setItems(R.array.preference_grid_entries, gridDialogListener);
        builder.create();
        builder.show();
    }
    private DialogInterface.OnClickListener gridDialogListener = new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            switch (which) {
                case 0:
                    break;
                case 1:

                    break;
                case 2:

                    break;
            }
        }
    };
```

I can show the list of values but i don't know how set the values on click.. is it possible? Thanks

Comment: May I ask why do you need to save the value manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your onClickListener like this

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this).edit().putString("preference_grid", 
        getResources().getStringArray(R.array.preference_grid_values)[which]).apply();
}
```

Comment: Man you saved me! Thank you!

Comment: Glad that it helped. If it works, please kindly accept as answer.

Comment: Sorry @Derek is it possible have the value of the selected item of the preference? `which` is the position..and if i want to see the "string" value for example in a toast?

Comment: Hope I understand correctly, I think you need `getResources().getStringArray(R.array.preference_grid_entries)[which]`